# No COM port, no /dev/tty* - tried different OS's, different cables

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

My devkit is an Amica V3, well two of them and both seem to have the same problem.

I tried to get the device to show up to then be able to install the NodeMCU firmware.

I did this on different computers and different OS's (Windows 7/10 + OS X 10.11.4), everytime making sure I installed SiLabs CP210X drivers first.
No sign of the devkit anywhere... When I unplug it and plug it back in the LED near the WiFi antenna blinks and then nothing. I pressed RST a few times, short/long, nothing.

I really hope you tell me that I'm stupid and that I should have RTFM so I would have not missed providing additional power to the board the first time you flash it... But I doubt that this is the case.

Comment: So long as the board (and the CP210X) is powered and connected then it should be visible as a USB device through device manager.  If not then also swap your USB cable because I have had this sort of prob with a duff cable before.

Comment: I tried a bunch of cables already. Any way to know that a certain cable should work?

Comment: @Pieter By using the particular cable to connect a different device (e.g. digicam).

Comment: @Pieter Side note, there's no such thing as "Amica V3". If you're certain it's V3 then it must be a LoLin. See http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/ for reference.

Comment: @MarcelStör This is the exact one: http://www.aliexpress.com/snapshot/7225210460.html?orderId=72049374201619

Comment: @Pieter Can't tell wether it's a fake but it's definitely not a LoLin V3 and Amica has only V1 and V2. But that doesn't help you fix your problem, sorry.

Comment: Should the blue LED normally be pulsing when connected with USB power or is it always that it quickly blinks when plugging in and then it remains off?

Comment: If you never could get it to work, could it be a faulty hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. It was the cable after all. Seems that I have 5 cables that it doesn't work with the 6th (from my Logitech keyboard) works...

Comment: Thanks! I made it in just five cables ;)